# foreach loop with array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have problems with my foreach loop for the `$overs` array. Here is my code:

```
$overs[result] = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$overs[market] = array('H6','H7','H8','H9','H10','H11','H12','H13');

foreach ($overs as $row) {
    echo $row['result'].'<br/>';
    echo $row['market'].'<br/>';
}
```

I do not get the results like...

```
0
H6
```

for the first items for example. All I get is an empty page. No errors. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's a lot wrong here, I suggest having a look through the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: you sure you get blank page no errors???

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 1):

Your $row becomes an array with two arrays.  You can't foreach like that.

Use normal for instead:

```
$overs['result'] = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$overs['market'] = array('H6','H7','H8','H9','H10','H11','H12','H13');

for($i=0; $i<count($overs["result"]);$i++) {
    echo $overs['result'][$i]."<br/>\n";
    echo $overs['market'][$i]."<br/>\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/kDObN

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for but try this out and see if this serves your purpose:

```
<?php
$a = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$b = array('H6','H7','H8','H9','H10','H11','H12','H13');

$c = array_combine($a, $b);

//print_r($c);

foreach($c as $k => $v){
    print $k.'<br>';
    print $v.'<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I like this better if the original keys aren't needed.

Comment: I agree. Good one!

Comment: @nerdlyist the original arrays are still there. $c is only used for the output.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a `foreach` consider using a `for` loop

I assume that the arrays in each will be the same size:

```
<?php
//You were missing the "'" for your keys btw
$overs['result'] = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$overs['market'] = array('H6','H7','H8','H9','H10','H11','H12','H13');

 for($i=0; $i < count($overs['result']); $i++){
     echo $overs['result'][$i] . '<br>';
     echo $overs['market'][$i] . '<br>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `$row` is the two arrays that you would then need to loop over.  But to get them one after the other as you show, you would probably need to loop one and access the other by key.  Obviously this only works correctly if the arrays are the same length and have the same keys:

```
foreach ($overs['result'] as $key => $val) {
    echo $val.'<br/>';
    echo $overs['market'][$key].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: I think you can handle different length arrays if you first check which is longest and foreach that. Then you do a if(isset()) on the other output. Just saying it can be handled. I think.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `$overs['result']` and `$overs['market']` in your first two lines,
which means it should be:

```
$overs['result'] = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$overs['market'] = array('H6','H7','H8','H9','H10','H11','H12','H13');
```

If so, your entire `foreach` is identical to the following:

```
echo $overs['result']['result'].'<br/>';
echo $overs['result']['market'].'<br/>';
echo $overs['market']['result'].'<br/>';
echo $overs['market']['market'].'<br/>';
```

Everything you're `echo`-ing doesn't exist, which means you should get errors similar to these:

```
Notice: Undefined index: result in xxx.php on line xxx
Notice: Undefined index: market in xxx.php on line xxx
```

You should add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the beginning of your script.